# Unity3d - Get GameObject height for a rotating object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get a GameObject's height. I have tried with:

```
this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size.y
```

But the problem with bounds is that it works with static objects only. When you have a moving object and if the rotation of the object is not perfectly aligned, the bounds (height) is not accurate anymore because it returns the height of the bounds that is a square and if you tilt an object like a plate you get the bounds height which is not accurate to the height of the object.

It is an Axis-Aligned Bounding Box (also known as an "AABB").

Please check the image I attached, there you can see the problem with moving objects and if you rotate them how the height is not accurate anymore.

[image]

Did anyone else have this kind of problem?

Any advice on how to get the object's height accurately?

Comment: Are you saying you would want the height from the rectangle on the left versus the rectangle on the right?(Which is rotated.)

Comment: @Eddge. No, I just demonstrated how Rendered bounds work if the object is moving or rotating. I will check all the answers here tomorrow and I will get back to everyone. Thank you all for great ideas. I will try them all and write my experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**One option is to use the Game Object's Collider.**

You can relatively easily find the height and width of a collider so this is one way you can measure the dimensions of a game object. The collider, for example a box collider on the game object, will have to fully encompasses the object. You can do this be resizing the collider until it snugly wraps around your game object. Then when you want to find a certain dimension of the object instead find that dimension on the collider and multiply by the Game Object's transform.scale.

Here are some examples I have tested.

Example 1:

```
CapsuleCollider m_Collider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
var height = m_Collider.height  * transform.localScale.y;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CapsuleCollider-height.html

or

Example 2:

```
   BoxCollider m_Collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
   var height = m_Collider.size.y  * transform.localScale.y;
   var width = m_Collider.size.x  * transform.localScale.x;
   var breadth = m_Collider.size.z  * transform.localScale.z;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider-size.html

Hopefully one of these will work for you.

If not, then a second inconvenient way you can find the height is to create 2 proxy objects as children at the top and bottom of your object. Afterwards find the scalar distance between them.

Comment: Not sure, this really solves the problem, It has alot of detail but the OP already explained that the bounds of the meshrenderer wouldn't work as it is axis-aligned.  Not to sure about the BoxCollider I will have to look into that but my gut is telling me it would still have the same size all around regardless of the rotation.  I asked OP for clarification on which height he is looking for...

Comment: Extents is the direction it travels in each direction(from the center, so an extent of 5 y would be a height of 10), which would be generated off of an axis-aligned box.  Your collider method may work if the size is the same regardless of the rotation, and if that is what he is looking for(Which I believe it is).

Comment: I will remove example 3 then.

Comment: Note that for your Example 1, there is no `height` property in `BoxCollider`.

Comment: Changed. It might only be for capsule collider. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CapsuleCollider-height.html

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about your answer. This returns the size of the collider, which does not take into account the scale of the gameObject's `transform`. For example, a box can have a scale of something like (1, 4, 1), but usually a BoxCollider is attached with a unit size so that the collider fits the size of the scaled box.

Comment: According to this page you are incorrect, at least with regards to the capsule collider. The transform factors into the calculation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CapsuleCollider-height.html . With regards to the box collider, you may be correct, but I actually don't know.

Comment: A `CapsuleCollider`'s height is also 1 and does not factor in a transform's scale. Give it a shot when you have access to the editor. I don't think you are interpreting the documentation correctly. Because "the capsule's height will be scaled by the transform's scale", it does not take `transform.scale` into account - height will generally be a value of 1 (for a cube or capsule shaped object) because the capsule's actual height adjusts automatically based on the object's transform..

Comment: You were right. transform.scale was not accounted for automatically when using my method.

Comment: I did`t tried with capsule collider because in my example I am using a box, so I tried the example 2, same idea but the box collider instead and I get a lot greater height, Idk why, the logic of this examples seems good...

Comment: When I tested this at home I had a box collider with height 10. When I increased the scale of the object to 2, the height went to 20, and at 3 it was 30, and so on. I can only guess as to why it did not work for you, but thanks for trying my solution. When I tested this it was pretty much just a copy paste of what I included here placed inside an update() with a debug.log() to track the height via console.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1: Use Mesh.bounds**

You can get the height using [`Mesh.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html). Unlike `MeshRenderer.bounds` (or `Renderer.bounds`), this is the axis-aligned bounding box of the mesh in its local space (i.e. not affected by the transform).

You still need to account for the scale of the GameObject using [`transform.lossyScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html), as follows:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Mesh _mesh;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float height = _mesh.bounds.size.y * transform.lossyScale.y;
        Debug.Log(height);
    }
}
```

(Note when using `transform.lossyScale`, the value can be slightly inaccurate. This is something to note if you need extreme accuracy. See [the documentation on transform.lossyScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html):)

> Please note that if you have a parent transform with scale and a child
>   that is arbitrarily rotated, the scale will be skewed. Thus scale can
>   not be represented correctly in a 3 component vector but only a 3x3
>   matrix. Such a representation is quite inconvenient to work with
>   however. lossyScale is a convenience property that attempts to match
>   the actual world scale as much as it can. If your objects are not
>   skewed the value will be completely correct and most likely the value
>   will not be very different if it contains skew too.

---

**Solution 2 (Workaround): Cache the unrotated MeshRenderer bounds**

Alternatively, if in your context you are able to instantiate the `GameObject` without a rotation and you only need to rotate the `GameObject` after initialization, one workaround solution is to cache the bounds from `MeshRenderer` in the `Awake` method, as follows:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Bounds _initialUnrotatedBounds;

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeUnrotatedBounds();
    }

    private void InitializeUnrotatedBounds()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(transform.rotation == Quaternion.identity);

        _initialUnrotatedBounds = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Use the cached bounds. Now, even for moving objects,
        // it doesn't matter if the rotation changes
        float height = _initialUnrotatedBounds.size.y;
        Debug.Log(height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used transform.lossyScale and it is very inaccurate when the object is moving and/or rotating. The idea to cache it at awake is great, I will try that too.

Comment: @AdrianIvasku interesting, are you sure the scale of your GameObject is not changing anywhere in your GameObject's hierarchy during the movement/rotation? The code I posted works for me for a basic example (e.g. in a blank Unity project, try a basic scaled Cube object with a few levels of nested transforms - lossyScale is fairly consistent while translating/rotating various transforms related to the cube). And personally, in my experience, I've never had any issues using `transform.lossyScale`, but perhaps I've been wrong that it's good enough for most cases.

Comment: For `lossyScale` accuracy errors, for example, I might get `2.000002` instead of `2` if there are rotations happening in a transform higher in the object's hierarchy, but I've never had an issue with it being very inaccurate

Comment: I have solved this bu using the collider height, that worked best for me. Also watchout if the pivot of the 3dObject is not in the center when you align the objects can create a lot of problems.